# Compare Android code coverage when running unit test in Jenkins

Tags: android, unit-testing, jenkins, gradle, code-coverage

I have setup an Android test project in Jenkins to run Robolectric unit tests with Jacoco plugin when there are new codes merged into master branch.

In Jenkins, is there a way that I can compare previous and current code coverage reports (in percentage)? 
When the coverage decreases, let the build job fail and notify the code contributor.